# Segmentation fault: arr[(i * 16) % arrLen] vs arr[i % arrLen]

Tags: c

Working on my assignment, more details in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594208/c-program-to-determine-levels-size-type-of-cache). If I use

```
arr[(i * 16) % arrLen] *= 2; // seg fault
```

vs

```
arr[i % arrLen] *= 2; // OK!
```

Why? **[Full source](https://gist.github.com/3787223)** see line 31. Why? I modulus the array length so it should be OK?

Comment: They are going to get you 2 different addresses - 1st one may not be valid?

Comment: Overflow is a failure mode, it produces negative numbers.

Comment: Are you in a 32-bit environment (e.g. x86)? I tried your code in my x64 machine and didn't get any error. So,  Hans Passant and Alexey Frunze seem to be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your full source:

1. You should be checking the return of malloc to make sure you were able to get that memory
2. You should be freeing the memory, you have a leak
3. The memory inside your arr array is uninitialized, you allocate it but don't set it to anything so you're getting (most likely) a large negitive number. This can be done by `memset(arr,0,arrLen);`
4. You `malloc(arrLen * sizeof(int))` however arrLen is created with a `/sizeof(int)`, so you're canceling your work there...

Regarding your seg fault, as others have stated your overflowing your array. You've created an array of ints. The then you're looping from 0 to reps (268,435,456) which is the max size of an int. When you try to multiply that by 16 you're overflowing and creating a negative offset.

Try multiplying the 16 into the initialization of reps:

```
int reps = 256 * 1024 * 1024 * 16;
```

Your compiler should throw a warning letting you know this exact thing:

```
warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
```

Comment: hmm I am not getting any errors, I'm new to C. I think I need a flag? Regarding (3) how can I zero or initialize my array?

Comment: Well it's not an error, it's a warning, and your not going to see it unless you make the `* 16;` I pointed out. What compiler/command are you using to build? I updated 3 with the code (note I only used arrLen for the length because of point 4).

Comment: RE: (4), actually, I think malloc is right tho? I am allocating `targetSizesInKB[sizeIndex] * 1024` bytes?

Answer (score 5):

`i * 16` can overflow into the negative range of signed integers. When you take modulo of a negative integer, you can get a negative remainder and that'll make your array subscript negative and result in an access outside of the array's allocated memory and sometimes a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the size of an `int` on your system is 32-bits, chances are you're causing an overflow and the result of `i * 16` is becoming negative. In a two's complement system, negative values are represented with a higher binary value.

```
int reps = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
```

So `reps = 268,435,456`, which is the value you're looping up until. The greatest value of `i` is therefore `268,435,455` and `268,435,455 * 16 = 4,294,967,280`.

The largest positive value a 32-bit `int` can represent is `2,147,483,647` (`4,294,967,295` for an `unsigned int`, so you haven't wrapped around the negatives yet), which means that result is being interpreted as a negative value.

Accessing a negative offset from `arr` is out of the bounds of your allocated memory, which causes undefined behaviour and fortunately a seg fault.