# Difference between std::system_clock and std::steady_clock?

Tags: c++, c++11, timer, c++-chrono

What is the difference between `std::system_clock` and `std::steady_clock`? (An example case that illustrate different results/behaviours would be great).

If my goal is to precisely measure execution time of functions (like a benchmark), what would be the best choice between `std::system_clock`, `std::steady_clock` and `std::high_resolution_clock`?

Comment: To start with, the system_clock may not be steady.

Comment: @James McNellis, that's true, but in practice the `system_clock` will only be non-steady on fantasy computers that the C++ standard tries to accommodate.  The thing is, `system_clock` maps to `std::time_t` values (C-style time), and I know of no platform (no non-exotic or ancient platform at least) where the C `std::time()` function is *not* the same as POSIX time.  And POSIX time is, by definition, "steady".

Comment: @CharlesSalvia I can't speak for other platforms, but the `system_clock` is not steady on Windows. On Windows, the system time may be altered to any arbitrary value by any sufficiently privileged user.  Additionally, the time synchronziation service may adjust the system time backwards if required. I expect most other platforms have similar features that permit adjustment of the system time.

Comment: @Charles: Most POSIX boxes I know of are similarly affected and will have their time change if the user changes the time.

Comment: Video answer to this question: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M&t=48m44s

Comment: @CharlesSalvia.  Per my own experience analyzing timing output from dozens of PC data acquisition systems, time from a computer is not steady.  Linux, Windows, and the specific system calls used are unknown, but the commonality is frequent negative time differences between subsequent time values.  Straight-line time is not the norm.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

From N3376:

20.11.7.1 [time.clock.system]/1:

> Objects of class `system_clock` represent wall clock time from the system-wide realtime clock.

20.11.7.2 [time.clock.steady]/1:

> Objects of class `steady_clock` represent clocks for which values of `time_point` never decrease as physical time advances and for which values of `time_point` advance at a steady rate relative to real time. That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

20.11.7.3 [time.clock.hires]/1:

> Objects of class `high_resolution_clock` represent clocks with the shortest tick period. `high_resolution_clock` may be a synonym for `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.

For instance, the system wide clock might be affected by something like daylight savings time, at which point the actual time listed at some point in the future can actually be a time in the past. (E.g. in the US, in the fall time moves back one hour, so the same hour is experienced "twice") However, `steady_clock` is not allowed to be affected by such things.

Another way of thinking about "steady" in this case is in the requirements defined in the table of 20.11.3 [time.clock.req]/2:

> In Table 59 `C1` and `C2` denote clock types. `t1` and `t2` are values returned by `C1::now()` where the call returning `t1` happens before the call returning `t2` and both of these calls occur before `C1::time_point::max()`. [ Note: this means `C1` did not wrap around between `t1` and `t2`. —end note ]
>
> Expression: `C1::is_steady`
>   Returns: `const bool`
>   Operational Semantics: `true` if `t1 <= t2` is always true and the time between clock ticks is constant, otherwise `false`.

That's all the standard has on their differences.

If you want to do benchmarking, your best bet is probably going to be `std::high_resolution_clock`, because it is likely that your platform uses a high resolution timer (e.g. `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows) for this clock. However, if you're benchmarking, you should really consider using platform specific timers for your benchmark, because different platforms handle this differently. For instance, some platforms might give you some means of determining the actual number of clock ticks the program required (independent of other processes running on the same CPU). Better yet, get your hands on a real profiler and use that.

Comment: This is correct, of course - but `system_clock` is the only clock that maps to C time (i.e. to `std::time_t` values), and the C `time()` function is almost always the same as POSIX time (I know of no platform where it's not) - and POSIX time is, by definition, "steady" - it's not affected by daylight savings or anything like that.  So the result is that in practice, `system_clock` *always* meets the requirements of `steady_clock`, except on exotic platforms that don't use POSIX time for C style time.

Comment: @Charles: Care to point out in the standard where that is the case? It seems to clearly indicate the opposite.

Comment: @Charles: Also, POSIX time is not "steady" -- if the user changes the time setting on their computer POSIX time will change. If you are cooking an egg, and need a timer that lasts 4 minutes, then you need it to last 4 minutes even if the current time is changed. If you've got a timer set for a meeting on the 5th at 3, then you absolutely need that timer to change if the local time changes. Hence the difference between `steady_clock` and `system_clock` here.

Comment: @BillyONeal I think that the remarks in your last comment are correct but daylight saving time is still not among the reasons `std::chrono::system_cklock` may change as you still have to convert its result to local time using the corresponding C function. So changes to time as caused by an NTP daemon or the user manually adjusting the clock would be a better example, IMHO. I do realize that there are bizarre systems that think in local time and for those, your example would apply.

Comment: @5gon: Nothing requires that `system_clock` be UTC.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia Please also note that since POSIX time is tied to UTC, and UTC has leap seconds (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Leap_seconds). That means that even if the time on a machine is never adjusted, C/POSIX time may be non-monotonic.

Comment: `std::system_clock` is not affected by daylight savings. `std::system_clock` is the number of periods (seconds, milliseconds, etc...) passed from the *epoch*, and that number of periods is not adjusted by daylight savings. It's a **calendar time** which is affected by daylight savings, so the different values of `std::system_clock::now` may be mapped to the same calendar time, but even in this case `tm_isdst` flag will be different. (see `system_clock::to_time_t` and `std::localtime`)

Comment: @anton_rh: There is no such requirement that the number of periods is not adjusted for DST.

Comment: UPDATE (Visual Studio 2015) The implementation of steady_clock has changed [.....] steady_clock is now based on QueryPerformanceCounter() and high_resolution_clock is now a typedef for steady_clock. Quoted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874757.aspx

Comment: Just checked - mingw32's version of high_resolution_clock is less precise than steady_clock. Doesn't sense sub-millisecond time intervals.

Comment: You are incorrect about the daylight saving time. DST do not affect unix time, They only affect how unix times are converted to human readable times. The system clock might be adjusted by the user, or by the system (if you have a process adjusting your system clock)

Answer (score 52):

Billy provided a great answer based on the ISO C++ standard that I fully agree with. However there is another side of the story - real life. It seems that right now there is really no difference between those clocks in implementation of popular compilers:

gcc 4.8:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC
   ...
#else
  typedef system_clock steady_clock;
#endif
  typedef system_clock high_resolution_clock;
```

Visual Studio 2012:

```
class steady_clock : public system_clock
{   // wraps monotonic clock
public:
  static const bool is_monotonic = true;    // retained
  static const bool is_steady = true;
};

typedef system_clock high_resolution_clock;
```

In case of gcc you can check if you deal with steady clock simply by checking `is_steady` and behave accordingly. However VS2012 seems to cheat a bit here :-)

If you need high precision clock I recommend for now writing your own clock that conforms to C++11 official clock interface and wait for implementations to catch up. It will be much better approach than using OS specific API directly in your code.
For Windows you can do it like that:

```
// Self-made Windows QueryPerformanceCounter based C++11 API compatible clock
struct qpc_clock {
  typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds                       duration;      // nanoseconds resolution
  typedef duration::rep                                  rep;
  typedef duration::period                               period;
  typedef std::chrono::time_point<qpc_clock, duration>   time_point;
  static bool is_steady;                                                // = true
  static time_point now()
  {
    if(!is_inited) {
      init();
      is_inited = true;
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER counter;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&counter);
    return time_point(duration(static_cast<rep>((double)counter.QuadPart / frequency.QuadPart *
                                                period::den / period::num)));
  }

private:
  static bool is_inited;                                                // = false
  static LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
  static void init()
  {
    if(QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency) == 0)
      throw std::logic_error("QueryPerformanceCounter not supported: " + std::to_string(GetLastError()));
  }
};
```

For Linux it is even easier. Just read the man page of `clock_gettime` and modify the code above.

Comment: The VC++ 2012 implementation has been acknowledged as a bug by MS's standard library maintainer.

Comment: For those interested, [this is a link to that bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443)

Comment: Boost uses QueryPerformanceCounter, so using boost::chrono is a good workaround this bug till Visual Studio 14 is released

Comment: And here are the POSIX calls those forward to on GCC 5.3.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36700301/895245

Comment: Latest MS STL std::system_clock wraps GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime/GetSystemTimeAsFileTime and std::steady_clock/std::high_resolution_clock wraps QueryPerformanceCounter https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2f03bdf361f7f153b4216c60a0d9491c0be13a73/stl/inc/__msvc_chrono.hpp#L638-L697

Answer (score 26):

**GCC 5.3.0 implementation**

C++ stdlib is inside GCC source:

- [`high_resolution_clock`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc_5_3_0_release/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L776) is an alias for `system_clock`
- [`system_clock`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc_5_3_0_release/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc#L54) forwards to the first of the following that is available:

  - `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)`
  - `gettimeofday`
  - `time`
- [`steady_clock`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc_5_3_0_release/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc#L82) forwards to the first of the following that is available:

  - `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`
  - `system_clock`

Then `CLOCK_REALTIME` vs `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is explained at: [Difference between CLOCK_REALTIME and CLOCK_MONOTONIC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523442/difference-between-clock-realtime-and-clock-monotonic)

Comment: cf.> MSVC: `high_resolution_clock` is an alias for `steady_clock` in std::chrono, and `steady_clock` uses QueryPerformanceCounter and QueryPerformanceFrequency. (Visual Studio 2015 and (maybe) beyond)

Answer (score 7):

[Relevant talk about chrono by Howard Hinnant](https://youtu.be/P32hvk8b13M?t=2875), author of `chrono`:

don't use `high_resolution_clock`, as it's an alias for one of these:

- `system_clock`: it's like a regular clock, use it for time/date related stuff
- `steady_clock`: it's like a stopwatch, use it for timing things.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe, the most significant difference is the fact that the starting point of `std::chrono:system_clock` is the 1.1.1970, so-called UNIX-epoch.
On the other side, for `std::chrono::steady_clock` typically the boot time of your PC and it's most suitable for measuring intervals.