# Improving a timer class based on <chrono>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have the following Timer class to simplify getting the time elapsed since an epoch:

```
#include <chrono>

class Timer {
  public:
    void start(void);
    template <typename duration_type>
    const duration_type time_elapsed(void);
  private:
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point epoch;
};

void Timer::start(void) {
  epoch = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

template <typename duration_type>
const duration_type Timer::time_elapsed(void) {
  return std::chrono::duration_cast<duration_type>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - epoch);
}

int main(void) {
  Timer timer;

  timer.start();

  // pointless loop to cause a delay
  for (int x = 1; x < 1000000; ++x) {
    x * x * x;
  }

  std::chrono::nanoseconds elapsed = timer.time_elapsed<std::chrono::nanoseconds>();
  std::cout << elapsed.count() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have a feeling I'm overcomplicating my class by making Timer::time_elapsed() a template function and ideally would like to simplify its usage to the following:

```
  std::chrono::nanoseconds elapsed = timer.time_elapsed();
  std::cout << elapsed.count() << std::endl;
```

Comment: How could I simplify usage of Timer::time_elapsed() to the second snippet?

Comment: Just `return duration_cast<nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - epoch);`

Comment: @sehe:  This comment is intended for your deleted answer.  I didn't downvote it.  And your last edit on it addressed exactly what I was commenting on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed a few things in your code and added proper usage of `std::chrono`. The changes list include:

1. I removed all `(void)` arguments from function calls because it is just not so C++ way :-)
2. I also removed `return 0;` from `main()` that is not needed in C++ because compiler will put it for you.
3. I typedef'ed a clock because it may be really hard to find a quality clock in current implementations right now. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263277/difference-between-stdsystem-clock-and-stdsteady-clock/13266477#13266477). Basically right now you may want to use your custom clock and thanks to `typedef` refactoring may be easier in the future.
4. I changed your wait loop to a C++11 sleep interface (you can randomise some duration there if you want - also with C++11 :-) ). That change was not need in that case but it nicely shows how `std::chrono` is also used in threading library.
5. I put your methods implementations inside a class to give compiler a chance to inline them. Alternatively you could use `inline` keyword explicity in implementation outside of the class.
6. I made your `time_elapsed()` method `const`
7. I removed unnecesary `const` from a return value of `time_elapsed()` method and added it on the other hand in usage of that method because in that exact place `const` is enough.
8. Last but not least, I modified your `time_elapsed()` method to return clock's native resolution in `return`. It is much better solution because you never loose data here. You may want to loose it when providing the data to user in a specific unit (ie. us). You have to use `duration_cast` there to tell the compiler that you agree on loosing some data and us resolution is enough for you.

I hope below code and above changes will be interesting to you.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

class Timer {
public:
  typedef high_resolution_clock Clock;
  void start()
  { epoch = Clock::now(); }
  Clock::duration time_elapsed() const
  { return Clock::now() - epoch; }
private:
  Clock::time_point epoch;
};

int main() {
  Timer timer;
  timer.start();

  // sleep some time
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(microseconds(40));

  const auto elapsed = timer.time_elapsed();
  std::cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(elapsed).count() << "us" << std::endl;
}
```

BTW, I didn't want to play with the class interface (I already did too many changes). If you are not bound to that interface yet I recommend following one that @sehe suggested. But do not use that `double` as a return value ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Return a helper class that stores now-epoch() and does the high precision cast on operator T from time elapsed.  Or, have a `time_elapsed_in_units<T>` method that looks like your time elapsed then have time elapsed return a struct that calls in units on operator T.

The over loading of the helper class's operator T let's you detect what type the called wants implicitly.