# is there a race condition when 2 processes attempt to read the system clock at the same time?

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, race-condition, real-time-clock

I have 2 processes (not threads) that are supposed to read the system clock at the same time. For this purpose, the first process uses

```html
QTime::currentTime();
```

and the second process uses

```html
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

But when I read the respective clock values read by these 2 processes, I find that there's always a difference of a few microseconds. Is it because the system clock is a shared resource, so one has to wait for the other to finish reading? Is it because the functions that read the system clock are not the same, so the time resolution is not the same? (but this seems very unlikely to me... because in my understanding the time resolution is set by the RTC, not the high level APIs)

I do not use any specific 'measure' to synchronize these 2 processes. The first is constantly attempting to read the system clock (it has a while(1)), the second reads the system clock when I launch it. So because the first process is always attempting to read the system clock, I guess there will probably be a 'race condition' when process 2 attempts the read the clock.

Comment: How are you coordinating the two processes to attempt to read at exactly the same time to begin with?

Comment: @jingx I edited my post to answer your question

Comment: This is nothing to do with what are usually known as *race conditions*, such as one process having to wait for another to free a resource.  This simply demonstrates the effective impossibility of observing two events at *exactly* the same time, where *exactly* is defined by the resolution of a modern computer clock.

Comment: Let's agree that **explicit and repeatable MCVE-formulated experiment** is a way to go, instead of fuzzy, opinionated hypotheses - so better than saying *"I guess there will probably be..."* **define a test** perhaps coded right on a commonly available platform - like on https://godbolt.org/z/ZVnO6R or similarly on https://tio.run/# ( having 680+ compiled / interpreted languages there ) --- and we all start to get a common ground to test a { **[PASS] | [FAIL]** }-scenario and promote any improved solution for the original problem --- that's fair to be both repeatable & quantitative, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only a race condition in the sense that you can not predict which process will report an earlier time, or if they will report the same time.  No harm is done by (near) simultaneous reads of the clock.  Both reports will be accurate to within the ability of the OS to deliver the information.  Depending on the OS, and hardware, it may or may not be possible for the two processes to report the same time.

It may or may not be a shared resource.  It might not even be the same clock under the hood.  `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is typically a `typedef` to either `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock`, and which one it is varies by platform.  On macOS/iOS/watchOS `high_resolution_clock` is a `typedef` to `steady_clock` and counts nanoseconds since the system booted.  This measure has no relationship to the time of day, or date on the calendar.

There is a description of the difference between `steady_clock` and `system_clock` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31553641/576911).