# How to measure execution time of a function?

Tags: c++, time

I've searched *SO* and found relevant questions answered but I'm confused about the three different clock definitions. Considering I compile with **Mingw** on **Windows**;

1. I wonder whether the code below is OK or not? (I do not really need nanoseconds or microseconds precision; just testing...)
2. Which one should I use?

- `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`
- `std::chrono::system_clock`
- `std::chrono::steady_clock`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
...
...
...
void printTimeElapsed(
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0,
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1)
{
    int64_t hh; // hour
    int64_t mm; // min
    int64_t ss; // sec
    int64_t ml; // millisec
    int64_t mc; // microsec
    int64_t ns; // nanosec

    ns = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t1 - t0).count();
    std::cout << ns << std::endl;
    mc = ns / 1000;
    ns %= 1000;
    ml = mc / 1000;
    mc %= 1000;
    ss = ml / 1000;
    ml %= 1000;
    mm = ss / 60;
    ss %= 60;
    hh = mm / 60;
    mm %= 60;

    std::cout
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << hh << ":"
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << mm << ":"
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << ss << "."
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ml << "."
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << mc << "."
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ns << std::endl;
    return;
}
...
...
...
int main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[])
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0;
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1;
    ...
    ...
    t0 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    /* call the function to be measured */
    t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    printTimeElapsed(t0, t1);
    ...
    ...
    return (0);       
}
```

Comment: std::chrono::steady_clock

Comment: Definitely `steady_clock`. `system_clock` can go backwards and `high_res_clock` is unreliable because it can be anything e.g. an alias for `sysyem_clock`.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552193/difference-between-steady-clock-vs-system-clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552193/difference-between-steady-clock-vs-system-clock)

Comment: Like you, I used `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` but it isn't consistently between SO, so the recommendation is using  `std::chrono::steady_clock` or `std::chrono::system_clock`. Check the note in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock

Comment: `std::chrono::steady_clock`

Answer (score -1):

`system_clock` is not *steady*: is subject to time adjustments.
`high_resolution_clock` is not guaranteed to be *steady*.

It means for users to use `steady_clock` for measurement, and because of this, implementers need to make the `steady_clock` of a high resolution.

Windows implementation of `steady_clock` should be based on `QueryPerformanceCounter` / `QueryPerformanceFrequency`, which is highest resolution of available API. This is true for MSVC, need to check for MinGW.