# Wrong output with 'chrono' library

Tags: c++

I was trying to calculate time elapsed during execution of my insertion sort function. So I did as follow.
P.S. - function is running correctly and sorting all the numbers.
Compiler - GCC
Windows

```
    auto start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    insertionSort(arr,1000);
    auto end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto diff = start - end; // gives 0 
    auto diff = end - start ; // still zero

    cout << chrono::duration <double, nano> (diff).count() << " ns" << endl;
```

Firstly I tried with 100 input it gave me `0 ms`  then I changed it to `ns` it still gave zero. Then I increased my input to `1000`. But sadly output is still zero. 
Is this correct way to  write chrono?
Someone suggested  to try 
`chrono::high_resolution_clock` it still gave me 0ns.

Or any method you guys can suggest to calculate time of a function.

UPDATE - So I was looking for solution so I found that if do something like sometimes it gave result.

```
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    insertionSort(arr,1000);
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto diff = end - start;

    cout << chrono::duration <double, nano> (diff).count() << " ns" << endl;


    ofstream  write;
    write.open("sort.txt");
    if(write)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
        {
            write<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Unable to open file.\n";
    }
```

I tried to write it in file now it giving me result if I choose `nano second`. 
But if I chose `mili` its still zero.

Does this mean insertion sort fast is exceptionally fast that C++ can't even measure it ?

Here is reproducable code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<chrono>
using namespace std;

void readData();
void insertionSort(int * , int );
void readData()
{

    int arr[1000];
    ifstream read;
    read.open("sort.txt",ios::binary);
    if(read)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int temp;
        while(read>>temp)
        {
            arr[i] = temp;
            ++i;
        }
        read.close();

    }
    else{
        cout<<"Unable to open file.\n";
    }


    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    insertionSort(arr,1000);
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto diff = end - start;

    cout << chrono::duration <double, nano> (diff).count() << " ns" << endl;

    ofstream  write;
    write.open("sort.txt");
    if(write)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
        {
            write<<arr[i]<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Unable to open file.\n";
    }

}
void insertionSort(int *arr , int size)
{
    for(int i = 1 ; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i -1 ;
        while(j>= 0 && arr[j]> key)
        {
            arr[j+1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[++j] = key;
    }

}
int main()
{
    readData();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: It might be something with optimizations. E.g., gcc at times computes everything at compile time eliminating any run time computations. You ought to use random numbers or something for performance testing.

Comment: @tkausl Tried but stil Zero :-(

Comment: `auto diff = start - end;` maybe  `auto diff = end - start;`

Comment: @ALX23z Can you explain in detail whatever you write in above comment.

Comment: @Alexander Still 0 .

Comment: try duration_cast<nanoseconds>(diff)

Comment: @M.M When I made them volatile it says.  No operator for `auto diff = end - start;` . operand are volatile.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/xJwvK8 works. Probably insertionSort was optimized by the compiler. try in godbolt.org to check the assembly

Comment: [This might be the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c), the sample program in [P0342](https://wg21.link/P0342) is quite similar to your code. The top answer has a workaround of sorts

Comment: You should be able to confirm by checking the generated assembly as to whether the timer checks have been reordered

Comment: Please post a minimal source code needed to reproduce the problem, at best include all the `#include`s and `int main()`. What is `arr`? What is `insertionSort`? What compiler are you using? What compiler options are you using? On what architecture are you running the program? Please post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @KamilCuk I have updated post. Please check again.

Comment: I get: `error: aggregate ‘std::ifstream read’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined` and `error: ‘insertionSort’ was not declared in this scope` errors when compiling your code. Is there `#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void insertionSort(int *arr , int size);
` missing? `compiler GCC Windows` - Are you using gcc with mingw?

Comment: @KamilCuk Ofc . they are supposed to be added. This much is obvious thing. >.< But still for your sake I have added everything.

Comment: On Windows, you can use `GetSystemTimeAsPreciseFileTime` to get 100 ns resolution.

Comment: What is the value of `i` after reading the elements from the file? Are you sure you are reading 1000 elements? How much time it takes to sort `srand(time(0)); for (auto& i: arr) { i = rand(); }`? Can you just check if something like (not working, it's a idea) `cout << chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); cout << chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` returns different values? There is most probably something you are not showing and missing. Are you sure you are running proper binary? Are you sure you are compiling right?

Comment: Yes everything works fine. I think desktop is exceptionally fast in sorting.

Comment: I thought you generate numbers randomly. If you read sorted file then insertionSort will take little to no time. Also, your PC might have a clock with low resolution, and if all 1000 elements happen to be inside the L3 cache at the start and be sorted then the whole sorting will take only a few K cycles which might be below the resolution you have.

Answer (score 2):

Use correct template argument to mark that you want milliseconds:

```
std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> diff = end - start ; // still zero
cout << diff.count() << " ms" << endl;
```

If it is still zero, maybe your operation is so fast that it take less than 1 millisecond to finish? Sorting array o 1000 elements is quite fast these days. Make it bigger or repeat several times.

For 10000 elems it is starting to return some values greater than 0. 
What is your environment? Maybe in your case high_resolution_clock is not available...
[Time measurements with High_resolution_clock not working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643279/time-measurements-with-high-resolution-clock-not-working-as-intended)

BTW I also have 0 as a result 50% of the time.

Comment: I changed that to nano-second but still zero.

Comment: Btw what's the need to write std::nano. I have already added namespaces std.

Comment: @vll Yes if clock is broken

Comment: @NikhilSharma it's not needed, but have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/9883438)

Answer (score 0):

As you are on Windows, you can use `QueryPerformanceFrequency()`. It will give you the number of ticks your system does in one second. So, you can use it to calculate the actual accuracy of your system clock:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    std::cout << 1.e9 / freq.QuadPart << "ns accuracy" << std::endl;
}
```

Everything attempt to measure something faster than this, will result in 0. Any attempt to measure something that is roughly in the same magnitude, will be inaccurate.

For example, on my system above code prints `100ns accuracy`.
If I run your code, it prints `1100ns` most of the time, sometimes `1200ns`, sometimes `1000ns`. Note how this is always a multiple of the accuracy.

One common way to overcome this is to run the code in question multiple times and take the average, like so:

```
constexpr int runs = 2000;

auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (int i = 0; i < runs; ++i)
    insertionSort(arr,1000);
auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

auto diff = end - start;

cout << std::chrono::duration <double, std::nano> (diff).count() / runs << " ns" << endl;
```

On my system this prints `1016.7ns`.