# Convert steady_clock::time_point (C++) to System::DateTime (C++/CLI)

Tags: c++, c++-cli, c++-chrono

I need to convert **C++** `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point` to **C++/CLI** `System::DateTime`.

**Background:**
I am wrapping a C++ library with a C++/CLI interface, to be used by a .NET app.
One of the C++ methods return a `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point`.
I thought it is appropriate to returns a `System::DateTime` from the C++/CLI wrapper method.
Thus the need to convert.

I am aware that if I had a `system_clock::time_point`,
I could have converted it to `time_t` as explained here: [How to convert std::chrono::time_point to calendar datetime string with fractional seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835577/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-calendar-datetime-string-with-fraction).
Then I could have used [DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-6.0#system-datetimeoffset-fromunixtimemilliseconds(system-int64)), and from it get a `System::DateTime`.
Another approach could have been to use [`time_since_epoch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch).
But neither `to_time_t` nor `time_since_epoch` are available for `std::chrono::steady_clock` (about `time_since_epoch` see: [chrono steady_clock not giving correct result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085871/chrono-steady-clock-not-giving-correct-result)).

However - I cannot change the C++ interface.
Also didn't manage to properly convert `steady_clock::time_point` to e.g. `system_clock::time_point`.

**The solution I came up with:**
I take current time from both `std::chrono::steady_clock` and `System::DateTime`,
then calculate offset from the `steady_clock::time_point`,
and finally apply this offset in reverse to the DateTime time.
I calculate the offset in milliseconds, and since the precision I am interested in is of seconds, it works well.
This method is shown in the code below.

But it feels a bit awkward. It is also sensitive to the requested precision.

**My question:** can you suggest a better way to do the conversion ?

```
using namespace System;
#include <chrono>

System::DateTime SteadyClockTimePointToDateTime(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point const & tCPP)
{
    auto nowCPP = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto nowCLI = System::DateTime::Now;
    long long milliSecsSinceT = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(nowCPP - tCPP).count();
    System::DateTime tCLI = nowCLI - System::TimeSpan::FromMilliseconds(static_cast<double>(milliSecsSinceT));
    return tCLI;
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::Console::WriteLine("System::DateTime::Now (for debug): " + System::DateTime::Now.ToString()); // print reference time for debug 
    auto tCPP = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();   // got the actual value from a C++ lib.

    System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(100); // pass some time to simulate stuff that was executed since the time_point was received.

    System::DateTime tCLI = SteadyClockTimePointToDateTime(tCPP);
    System::Console::WriteLine("System::DateTime (converted):      " + tCLI.ToString()); // should show a time very close to System::DateTime::Now above
    return 0;
}
```

Output example:

```
System::DateTime::Now (for debug): 23-May-22 16:41:04
System::DateTime (converted):      23-May-22 16:41:04
```

**Note:** I added the C++ tag because the question is not a pure C++/CLI issue.
E.g. there might be a solution involving conversion between std::chrono clocks that will enable an easy further conversion to System::DateTime (as mentioned above regarding `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`).

Comment: Your chosen approach is the same as my recommendation here (substituting `System::DateTime` for `std::system_clock`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622684/103167  Yours isn't the shortest/cleanest code possible (for example, use `nowCLI.AddMilliseconds()` instead of that `TimeSpan` mess and get rid of the sign problem by changing the line above to `tCPP - nowCPP`) but the approach is correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, I was not aware of `DateTime.AddMilliseconds`. If you'd like to write an answer and explain all the improvments for my code I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is sound, but the code can be made shorter and easier to read with a couple small changes:

```
template<typename Rep, typename Period>
System::TimeSpan DurationToTimeSpan(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> const& input)
{
     auto milliSecs =
              std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(input).count();
     return System::TimeSpan::FromMilliseconds(milliSecs);
}

System::DateTime SteadyClockTimePointToDateTime(
                          std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point const & tCPP)
{
    auto const nowCPP = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto nowCLI = System::DateTime::Now;
    auto tCLI = nowCLI + DurationToTimeSpan(tCPP - nowCPP);
}
```

The specific changes made are:

1. Hide use of the duration cast and `TimeSpan` factory function invocation in another helper function.<sup>1</sup>
2. Reverse the order of subtraction of `nowCPP` and `tCPP`, to avoid having to reverse the sign later.
3. Add `const` to local variables having native type and which will not be changed.  .NET types sadly are not const-correct, because `const`-ness is only respected by the C++/CLI compiler and not the languages in which the .NET library is written.
4. Avoid explicit type conversion between the return value of `count()` and the parameter of `AddMilliseconds`.  If for some platform there is a different duration representation and implicit conversion doesn't work, it's better to have the compiler tell the maintenance programmer.

---

Note that the result of this function does NOT provide the "steady clock" guarantee.  In order to do so, one should generate a single `time_point`/`DateTime` pair and save it for later reuse.

---

<sup>1</sup> Another choice would be to use the `AddMilliseconds` member function, which replaces a call to `TimeSpan` factory function and overloaded `operator-`:

```
System::DateTime SteadyClockTimePointToDateTime(
                          std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point const & tCPP)
{
    auto const nowCPP = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto nowCLI = System::DateTime::Now;
    auto const milliSecsUntilT =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(tCPP - nowCPP).count();
    auto tCLI = nowCLI.AddMilliseconds(milliSecsUntilT);
    return tCLI;
}
```