# Is it correct to use std::chrono::steady_clock time across the system?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a file with header time as `std::chrono::steady_clock` parameter. **The different server will be writing them on the disk.** During the usage of file, I will be comparing them to find the latest time.
I am confused with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock

**Updates:**

**Q:** Whether the comparison provides me the latest file or not?

**Q:** Should I use the system_clock instead of steady_clock?

Comment: What are you confused by exactly? What are the problems you think there could be?

Comment: explaination of steady_clock and I doubt that I should use system_clock

Comment: Ok, the dupe should cover that. If you have a more specific question, please edit that in, and explain why the dupe doesn't answer your question.

Comment: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263277/difference-between-stdsystem-clock-and-stdsteady-clock)

Comment: thats fine though that difference question do not answer my particular query

Comment: From the linked page : *"This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals."* It does not seem appropriate for time stamping in a file. For example it seems like it could be time since the process started, and different processes would not agree on the current `steady_clock` time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux updated post

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you are right but the question is closed as a duplicate. So, I dont have that option. I have request to reopen. Lets see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** Whether the comparison provides me the latest file or not?

Answer:
With reference to link shared above:

> "This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be
> time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring
> intervals."

It does not seem appropriate for time stamping in a file. For example it seems like it could be time since the process started, and different processes would not agree on the current `std::chrono::steady_clock` time.

Retrieved from @François Andrieux's comment might help someone here.

**Q:** Should I use the system_clock instead of steady_clock?

**Answer:** When we are working on different servers or systems and trying to compare the `std::chrono::steady_clock` it will be wrong. **Use std::chrono::system_clock instead.**