# Avoid use of gettimeofday() API

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

`gettimeofday()` is hardware dependent with RTC.

Can some one suggest how we can avoid the use of the same in Application Programming. 
How we can approach the use of System ticks ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: What about just using `time()`? Seconds aren't enough: Use `clock_gettime()` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Comment: are you sure this api reads values from system tick. i dont think so..as there is an api provided to settime ..

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-timers-list/ this is somewhat we need to follow

Comment: `clock_gettime()` supports different (system) clocks. You propably are after `CLOCK_BOOTTIME`, which I suspect cannot be set via `clock_settime()`. Test it.

Comment: will this api work fine if i remove RTC from my system

Comment: Sry, that's beyond my expertise. But I could imagine: Yes

Comment: Please expand on your question.  What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe this SO question helps? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12392278/1401351

Comment: hi !! peter !! i want to get system ticks .. this is sufficient to understand.. the link you provided depends on the RTC .

Answer (score 1):

To get time in ticks you might like to use [`times()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html).

However is is not clear whether those ticks are measured from boot-time.

[From `man times`:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html)

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> times() returns the number of clock ticks that have elapsed since an
>   arbitrary point in the past.   [...]
>
> [...]
>
> **NOTES**
>
> On Linux, the "arbitrary point in the past" from which the return
>   value of times() is measured has varied across kernel versions.  On
>   Linux 2.4 and earlier this point is the moment the system was booted.
>   Since Linux 2.6, this point is (2^32/HZ) - 300 (i.e., about 429
>   million) seconds before system boot time.  This variability across
>   kernel versions (and across UNIX implementations), combined with the
>   fact that the returned value may overflow the range of clock_t, means
>   that a portable application would be wise to avoid using this value.
>   To measure changes in elapsed time, use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) instead.

Reading this using `clock_gettitme()` with the `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` timer might be the more secure and more portable way to go. If this function and/or timer is available for system without RTC I'm not sure. Others are encouraged to clarfiy this.