# Measuring execution time of a program

Tags: profiling, execution-time

The link [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/settimeofday.2.html) says that `gettimeofday()` sets a structure which contains number of seconds and microseconds since ***Epoch*** (please tell me what Epoch is). With that thing in mind I set a structure before and after calling sleep function with parameter 3. So the total time difference setting of these structure is 3 seconds or 3000000 microseconds but it seem to give some wrong output. Where am I getting wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct timeval start,end;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    sleep(3);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    cout<<start.tv_usec<<endl;
    cout<<end.tv_usec<<endl;
    cout<<end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "it seem to give some wrong output."  Q: Would you be kind enough to *share* an example?

Comment: `711721
711870
149` is one of the output and it keeps changing everytime I run it, even the difference of the two. @paulsm4

Comment: Suggestion: try [clock_gettime()](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time?gclid=CIn-h46U4MsCFQmqaQodLRwPqg) instead (for Linux).  If Windows, try [QueryPerformanceCounter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Tried using clock_gettime(). The difference of two I got now is 147767, which again is not equal to 3,000,000,000 nanoseconds and this too keeps changing on every other execution. Any idea @paulsm4

Comment: Q: Are you actually delaying 3 seconds?  Q: What happens if you increase it to 10 seconds (which is easier to count).  There are actually lots of reasons "sleep (3)" might not actually delay a full three seconds.  The link I cited tells you how to create your own "sleep(), if you wish.

Comment: @paulsm4 When I changed 3 to 10, `947291850
947441421
149571` was my output and yes it did wait for 10 secound before it displayed the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the point you're missing:

`unsigned long time_in_micros = 1000000 * tv_sec + tv_usec;`

To get the elapsed time in microseconds, you need to *ADD* "seconds" to "microseconds".  You can't just *ignore* the tv_sec field!

Sample code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct timeval start,end;
    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    sleep(3);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    printf ("start: %ld:%ld\n", start.tv_sec, start.tv_usec);
    printf ("end:   %ld:%ld\n", end.tv_sec, end.tv_usec);
    printf ("diff:  %ld:%ld\n",
      end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec, end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);

    gettimeofday(&start,NULL);
    sleep(10);
    gettimeofday(&end,NULL);
    printf ("start: %ld:%ld\n", start.tv_sec, start.tv_usec);
    printf ("end:   %ld:%ld\n", end.tv_sec, end.tv_usec);
    printf ("diff:  %ld:%ld\n", 
      end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec, end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}
```

Corresponding output:

```
start: 1459100430:214715
end:   1459100433:215357
diff:  3:642
start: 1459100433:215394
end:   1459100443:217024
diff:  10:1630
```

gettimeofday() links:

- http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday
- https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time
- [Measure time in Linux - time vs clock vs getrusage vs clock_gettime vs gettimeofday vs timespec_get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392278/measure-time-in-linux-getrusage-vs-clock-gettime-vs-clock-vs-gettimeofday/12480485#12480485)